# Trying to loop between CSS classes/hover states - Jquery

Tags: jquery, timer, hover, setinterval

I am trying to create a function in JQuery which animates a couple links between their non-hovered and hover states indefinitely until my `abortTimer` function is fired.  I would like to animate between `a.mus-plr` and `a.earbuds` at opposing times, so when one of the elements has it's `'.hover'` class enabled, the other would not have it's `'.hover'` class enabled. I would like each element to switch between it's hover states every 3000 milliseconds.

Any help would be much appreciated!  I can't seem to get this to work.  I'm thinking it might be a problem with how I've defined my setInterval timer.  Thanks!!

**JQuery file:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tid = setInterval(animateControls, 4000);
    function animateControls() {
        $("a.mus-plr").delay(2000).addClass('hover').delay(2000).removeClass('hover');
        $("a.earbuds").addClass('hover').delay(2000).removeClass('hover');
    }
    function abortTimer() {
        clearInterval(tid);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) the `hover` class each time your interval timer expires, assuming they start off with one having and the other not having the hover class.

**Edited** to stop the automated toggle when an element is hovered.

```
$(function() {
     var doToggle = true;

     $('a.mus-plr').removeClass('hover');
     $('a.earbuds').addClass('hover');

     var tid = setInterval( function() {
          if (doToggle) $('a.mus-plr, a.earbuds').toggleClass('hover');
     }, 2000);

     setTimeout(function() {
        if (tid) clearInterval(tid);
        $('a.mus-plr,a.earbuds').removeClass('hover');
     }, 30000); // stop toggling after 30 seconds

     $('a.mus-plr,a.earbuds').hover( function() {
           doToggle = false;
     }, function() {
           doToggle = true;
     });
});
```

Comment: That's perfect!  One more quick question which I forgot to mention.  If I wanted to set it so that this loop stops/pauses when the mouse is hovering over `a.mus-plr` or `a.earbuds` and then resumes /begins again once the mouse has left, how would I go about doing that?  I'm assuming I use the JQuery `.hover()` function, but I'm not sure where to implement it in the above loop.

Comment: @kaffolder You could set an external guard variable to true or false depending on whether the toggle should actually happen. Have your `hover` handler set the guard to false when hovering and true when not.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?  I'm not sure if I understand this. Thank you so much!

Comment: @kaffolder - I've updated my example to turn off the automated toggle when one of the elements is hovered.