# Looping between hover states

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sort of silly website request - they want the hover states to animate because they think no one will know there are links there otherwise...

Anyway... I created a slideshow to show the effect I'm trying to create - but now I can't get it to work with the jQuery code. I found what I thought was an answer here: [Trying to loop between CSS classes/hover states - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964257/trying-to-loop-between-css-classes-hover-states-jquery)

but even incorporating this new code, the animation/toggle doesn't work.

I assume I'm missing something obvious - can anyone help?

Here's the slideshow version to show effect I'm going for: 
http://test.fatcat-studios.com/gtm/index.html 
but I want to do this with jQuery so when you interact with it, the correct hover state shows upon actual mouse over.

And here's my jQuery code:

```
    $(function() {
    var doToggle = true;                            
    $('a.res').removeClass('hover');
    $('a.com').addClass('hover');                           
    var tid = setInterval( function() {
    if (doToggle) $('a.res, a.com').toggleClass('hover');
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {

    if (tid) clearInterval(tid);

    $('a.res,a.com').removeClass('hover');
    }, 30000); // stop toggling after 30 seconds

    $('a.res,a.com').hover( function() {
    doToggle = false;
    }, function() {
    doToggle = true;
    });
    });
```

Any help is much appreciated! Let me know if there's more info needed.
Haikukitty

Comment: The link that u gave http://test.fatcat-studios.com/gtm/index.html, it doesn't do anything. Am I correct?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What isn't working?

Comment: OK - sorry - I sped up the interval on the test.fatcat-studios.com/gtm slideshow to show WHAT I'm trying to achieve - it was really slow before. But I want to achieve it with a jQuery toggle function (I think)

Comment: To try to be more clear - when someone comes to the page, which is here: http://test.fatcat-studios.com/gtm/index3.html  (styles not set yet) - I want the RESIDENTIAL / COMMERCIAL links to automatically loop back and forth between their off states and their hover states, until the user interacts with the link. The slideshow just shows what I'm hoping to achieve. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(function() {
    var autoToggle = true;
    var $togglers = $('a.res, a.com');

    var tid_1,
        tid_2 = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(tid_1);
        $togglers.removeClass('hover');
        autoToggle = false;
    }, 30000); // stop toggling after 30 seconds

    $togglers.hover(function() {
        clearInterval(tid_1);
        $togglers.removeClass('hover');
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    }, function() {
        if(autoToggle) {
            $('a.res').removeClass('hover');
            $('a.com').addClass('hover');
            tid_1 = setInterval(function() {
                $togglers.toggleClass('hover');
            }, 2000);
        }
        else {
            $togglers.removeClass('hover');
        }
    }).triggerHandler('mouseout');
});
```

Comment: Beautiful! That works. I had gotten it to the point of toggling, but couldn't get it to pause and show the hover state on mouseover - this does it! Thank you SO much!

Comment: Haikukitty, it could be improved slightly. It's a small issue but as it stands, the 30 second timeout removes the 'hover' state unconditionally. It should probably do so only if no 'mouseover' condition exists. To see what I mean, hover over one of the links and wait for the 30 seconds to expire.

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean. But honestly, I'm pretty sure no one will ever be bothered by it. Thanks again!!

ETA: Nevermind - stupid error!---> {Any reason I can't see my background images on hover with this function? Before I spend too much time troubleshooting - but I don't see anything that would interfere with a bg image being set in my css styles...

Comment: Haikukitty, here's [another version](http://jsfiddle.net/gFy6p/4/) that fixes the 30s timeout issue and is generally tidier. I can't think of a reason why bg images should be affected by any of this.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot! Yeah, the background image was just a syntax error. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to simulate CSS hover state with JS. However, if you want a simple jQuery solution, this should do what you want ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lexy0202/eSAmj/)).

CSS (use :hover pseudo-class)

```
#clicky {
    color:#000;
}

#clicky:hover {
    color:#FFBF00;
}
```

​JS

```
yep = true; // just a global var to stop it flashing when the user hovers
// you may want to persist this differently

$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        if (yep) {
            var $c = $('#clicky');
            $c.css({color: $c.hasClass('active') ? '#000' : '#FFBF00'}).toggleClass('active');
        }
    }, 1 * 1000);

    $('#clicky').hover(function() {
        yep = false;
    }, function() {
        yep = true;
    });
});​
```

Comment: That seems like it could work, it doesn't need to be particularly fancy! Is there a way to set the start time so that with two links, (two separate functions) one will delay start until the other goes off? (Does that make sense?) Or is there no way to do that with this solution? Looping states seems like it should be easy to do, but I'm having a ridiculous amount of trouble finding a solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you not change them both in the same function (the anonymous function inside `setInterval`)?